# CRM 2011: How to call Workflow activity on relationship entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

I have a relationship entity Fixture_In_Series which holds a relationship between FIXTURE and SERIES entity. Whenever any new fixture is associated/linked to a series a new record is generated in fixture_in_series.

I want my custom built Workflow Activity to fire whenever a new Fixture is associated to a Series and then it will do a job.

I can see Fixture and Series entity in the list when creating a new process but obviously Fixture_In_Series is not there as it is a relationship only.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe associate event is not possible to attach.

So i suggest you to use the OnUpdate\OnCreate Entity event and check if the lookup field Fixture has been filled.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying it sounds like you are using a native many to many relationship between Fixture and Series. These entities cannot trigger workflows.

Two options that I see. Change your workflow to a plug-in and trigger it on the associate event.

Or, re-create your relationship as a custom many to many relationship. This involves you creating the intersection entity yourself, then you can trigger workflows on the update/create of the records in the intersection entity.